# Character degrees of extensions of 2^B_2(q^2)

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

The outer automorphism group of the Suzuki simple group
${}^2B_2 (2^{2m+1})$, $m \geq 1$ is cyclic of order $2m+1$ and
is generated by a field automorphism $\varphi$ of order $2m+1$.
For any almost-simple group  $S \leq H \leq {\rm Aut}(S)$ with
$S={}^2B_2 (2^{2m+1})$, the group $H/S$ is cyclic.
I would like to know

1. the action of $\varphi$ on the conjugacy classes of the group $S$, and
2. the set of complex character degrees of the group $H$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For insight into this kind of computation, it's probably useful to look at the small cases Sz(8) and especially Sz(32) included in the *Atlas of Finite Groups*.   For example, $S=$Sz(32) involves $m=2$, while $\varphi$ has order 5; here the *Atlas* seems to answer both of your questions, if you unpack the notational conventions.     But in general what you are asking for probably gets much longer computationally even though the character degrees for the Suzuki groups are worked out in Suzuki's original papers.   (Those papers may also be worth consulting.)

Answer (score 3):

The action of $\varphi$ on the conjugacy classes of the Suzuki groups
${\rm Sz}(2^{2m+1}) = {}^2B_2 (2^{2m+1})$
is described by Lemma 3.3 in:

- Stefan Kohl, [Counting the orbits on finite simple groups under the action
  of the automorphism group - Suzuki groups vs. linear groups](http://dx.doi.org/10.1081/AGB-120004501).
  Comm. Algebra 30 (2002), no. 7, 3515-3532. [(PDF)](http://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/articles/countorb.pdf).

Further, denoting by $\omega(G)$ the number of orbits on a group $G$ under
the action of its automorphism group, Theorem 3.4 in that paper says that we always have
$$
  \omega({}^2B_2 (2^{2m+1})) \ = \ \omega({\rm PSL}(2,2^{2m+1})) + 2.
$$
A graphical illustration of the correspondence between the orbits on
${}^2B_2 (2^{2m+1})$ and the ones on ${\rm PSL}(2,2^{2m+1})$ is shown
in Figure 1.